# Parsing command-line options in C#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, command-line-arguments

I've seen people write custom classes to more easily handle command line options in various languages. I wondered if .NET (3.5 or lower) has anything built in so that you don't have to custom-parse things like:

> myapp.exe file=text.txt

Comment: Jon, I agree -- didn't see that question before posting an answer here.  I'll cross-post my answer over there (I'm surprised that no one mentioned CSharpOptParse as of yet).

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76119461/1319086

Answer (score 7):

For quick-and-dirty utilities where you don't need anything sophisticated, many times a console application takes command lines of the form:

```
program.exe command -option1 optionparameter option2 optionparameter
```

etc.

When that's the case, to get the 'command', just use `args[0]`

To get an option, use something like this:

```
var outputFile = GetArgument(args, "-o");
```

Where `GetArgument` is defined as:

```
string GetArgument(IEnumerable<string> args, string option)
    => args.SkipWhile(i => i != option).Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is another possible approach.  Very simple but it has worked for me in the past.

```
string[] args = {"/a:b", "/c:", "/d"};
Dictionary<string, string> retval = args.ToDictionary(
     k => k.Split(new char[] { ':' }, 2)[0].ToLower(),
     v => v.Split(new char[] { ':' }, 2).Count() > 1 
                                        ? v.Split(new char[] { ':' }, 2)[1] 
                                        : null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: **No.**

But there are parsers that people have built such as...

Arguably the best out there: [C# Command Line Argument Parser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/command_line.aspx)

Comment: I meant built-in to the framework, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly old post, but here's something I devised and use in all of my console applications. It's just a small snippet of code that can be injected into a single file and everything will work.

http://www.ananthonline.net/blog/dotnet/parsing-command-line-arguments-with-c-linq

Edit: This is now available on [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/declcmdparser), and is part of the open-source project [CodeBlocks](http://codeblocks.codeplex.com/).

It was devised to be declaratively and intuitively used, like so (another usage example [here](http://codeblocks.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Declarative%20command%20line%20parser%20sample&referringTitle=Home)):

```
args.Process(
    // Usage here, called when no switches are found
    () => Console.WriteLine("Usage is switch0:value switch:value switch2"),

    // Declare switches and handlers here
    // handlers can access fields from the enclosing class, so they can set up
    // any state they need.
    new CommandLine.Switch(
        "switch0",
        val => Console.WriteLine("switch 0 with value {0}", string.Join(" ", val))),
    new CommandLine.Switch(
        "switch1",
        val => Console.WriteLine("switch 1 with value {0}", string.Join(" ", val)), "s1"),
    new CommandLine.Switch(
        "switch2",
        val => Console.WriteLine("switch 2 with value {0}", string.Join(" ", val))));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to use a library and something simple is good enough you could do this:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Skip(1).ToArray();
Func<string, string> lookupFunc = 
    option => args.Where(s => s.StartsWith(option)).Select(s => s.Substring(option.Length)).FirstOrDefault();

string myOption = lookupFunc("myOption=");
```

;