# How can I obtain the named arguments from a console application in the form of a Dictionary<string,string>?

Tags: c#, .net, string, parsing, console-application

I have a console application called MyTool.exe

What is the simplest way to collect the named arguments passed to this console applicaiton and then to put them in a `Dictionarty<string, string>()` which will have the argument name as the key and the value as the argument?

for example:

```
MyTool foo=123432 bar=Alora barFoo=45.9
```

I should be able to obtain a dictionary which will be:

```
MyArguments["foo"]=123432 
MyArguments["bar"]="Alora"
MyArguments["barFoo"]="45.9"
```

Comment: Couldn't you use a more standard format thus allowying your appliction to interop with others better? Have a peek at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c

Answer (score 34):

Use this Nuget package

- V1.9.x - [Command Line Parser Library](https://commandline.codeplex.com/) <sup>(CodePlex - Going away soon and out of date)</sup>
- V2+ - [Command Line Parser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline) <sup>(Ongoing support)</sup>

Takes  seconds to configure and adds instant professional touch to your application.

```
// Define a class to receive parsed values
class Options {
  [Option('r', "read", Required = true,
    HelpText = "Input file to be processed.")]
  public string InputFile { get; set; }

  [Option('v', "verbose", DefaultValue = true,
    HelpText = "Prints all messages to standard output.")]
  public bool Verbose { get; set; }

  [ParserState]
  public IParserState LastParserState { get; set; }

  [HelpOption]
  public string GetUsage() {
    return HelpText.AutoBuild(this,
      (HelpText current) => HelpText.DefaultParsingErrorsHandler(this, current));
  }
}

// Consume them
static void Main(string[] args) {
  var options = new Options();
  if (CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, options)) {
    // Values are available here
    if (options.Verbose) Console.WriteLine("Filename: {0}", options.InputFile);
  }
}
```

Comment: 2.0.*-beta seems to change things a little: https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline - including a different options layout.

Comment: @WernerCD Guess we need to update this answer once it gets released. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 15):

Here's how this can be done in the most simple way:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var arguments = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (string argument in args)
        {
            string[] splitted = argument.Split('=');

            if (splitted.Length == 2)
            {
                arguments[splitted[0]] = splitted[1];
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that:

- Argument names are case sensitive
- Providing the same argument name more than once does not produce an error
- No spaces are allowed
- One = sign must be used

Comment: Overwriting a key is a deadly type of "silent error".   The program does not complain, and misinterprets what the user specifies.  Granted for the majority of cases it won't matter.

Comment: hova: this serves as an example.

Comment: This is my approach, as well. I like the concept of using "pure" C# and .NET as opposed to third-party libs, when viable.

Answer (score 4):

if you have a "=" in your parameter values, a safer option would be:

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> ResolveArguments(string[] args)
{
    if (args == null)
        return null;

    if (args.Length > 0)
    {
        var arguments = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (string argument in args)
        {
            int idx = argument.IndexOf('=');
            if (idx > 0)
                arguments[argument.Substring(0, idx)] = argument.Substring(idx+1);
        }
        return arguments;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that instead of "if (args.Length > 1)", you should have "if (args.Length >= 1)" or "if (args.Length > 0)". In the case of exactly 1 argument, your code returns null.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine**.

```
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddCommandLine(args) // here
    .Build();
```

Than you can execute your app like this:

```
MyConsoleApplication.exe --myParameterName myvalue
```

Check [this blog post](https://pradeepl.com/blog/dotnet/configuration-in-a-net-core-console-application/) and [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#command-line-arguments) for details.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why this code is bad? hova?

```
        var arguments = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var item in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs())
        {
            try
            {
                var parts = item.Split('=');
                arguments.Add(parts[0], parts[1]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // your error handling here....
            }
```

Comment: why have you put Environment.GetCommandLineArgs instead of just args?

Comment: Then, the code example is independent of where you run it, just paste it in somewhere, and it will run.