# Regular Expression for catch command line argument groups

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core

If I have the following scenario for this command line application I'm building...

```
update DIFFICULTY=1 DESCRIPTION="some long run on description"
```

I want to capture `DIFFICULTY=1` and I want to capture `DESCRIPTION="some long run on description"` as two separate groups, and if I eventually add on more to the api, potentially another `DESCRIPTION` field, how would I go about doing so using regex. Casing doesn't matter so much on the left side.

I've got this so far, but it doesn't catch the whole quoted text of description, nor do I think it'd separate potential future additional description fields.

```
/([A-Z])([\w="])+/g
```

I'm using .NET cores regular expression library to figure this out as an FYI, in case there are any gotchas in js regular expressions.

Comment: I think this might be useful for you (highest ranked answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429970/how-can-i-obtain-the-named-arguments-from-a-console-application-in-the-form-of-a

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, you can use regexes, but it would look like that:

```
(?<=\s)(\w+=(?:"(?:(?<=\\)"|[^"])+"|[\S]+))
```

[(Try it here)](https://regex101.com/r/JEtgX5/4)

Not every problem should be solved using regexes though, and I suggest you see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429970/how-can-i-obtain-the-named-arguments-from-a-console-application-in-the-form-of-a) provided by [*LocEngineer*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4579015/locengineer) on the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a conditional regex:

```
\b(?P<key>[A-Z]+)=(")?(?P<value>(?(2)[^"]*|\S+))
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/g0KRhj/1/).

---

More verbose, this means:

```
\b               # a word boundary
(?P<key>[A-Z]+)  # only UPPERCASE letters -> group "key"
=                # =
(")?             # capture quotes if they are present
(?P<value>       # start group "value"
    (?(2)[^"]*   # if quotes were present, match anything up to new quotes
    |            # ... or ...
    \S+)         # anything not a whitespace, 1+ times
)
```